# Knowing if a table is in "native" Word Format

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm sorry if this is a really dumb question, but I need to submit a document in Microsoft Word format and furthermore all tables must also be in the "native format" (their words).

For the tables in my document, I first created them in Excel and then copied them into Word (using the default paste option, which seems to be similar to choosing the .rtf option in paste special). The tables are not linked back to Excel, they are independent. Also, when I click on the table, the ribbon switches to "Table Layout" options.

All this would seem to imply that the tables are in the correct format, but I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: There is no way for us to know what "their words" mean. It likely means the table is to be formatted properly with the rest of the document. Or they expect it to be an actual table in the document and not an image of one. We can only guess.

Comment: As CharlieRB says, there is no way to know what was meant.  But one logical interpretation would be something that behaves as if it was created in Word.  That definition would preclude something that could not be manipulated using Word's built-in functions.  Pasting something from Excel could potentially incorporate features that are not available in Word.  When you say you need to submit it, that implies that someone else will need to be able to modify it (and their limitation to Word could be what underlies this).